# inserting node in yaml with ruamel

Tags: python, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I would like to have printed the following layout:

`extra:
  identifiers:
      biotools: 
          - http://bio.tools/abyss`

I'm using this code to add nodes:

`yaml_file_content['extra']['identifiers'] = {}

yaml_file_content['extra']['identifiers']['biotools'] = ['- http://bio.tools/abyss']`

But, instead, I'm getting this output, that encapsulates the tool in []:

`extra:
  identifiers:
     biotools: ['- http://bio.tools/abyss']`

I have tried other combinations but didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dash in `- http://bio.tools/abyss` indicates a sequence element and is added on output if you dump a Python list in block style.

So instead of doing:

```
yaml_file_content['extra']['identifiers']['biotools'] = ['- http://bio.tools/abyss']
```

you should be doing:

```
yaml_file_content['extra']['identifiers']['biotools'] = ['http://bio.tools/abyss']
```

and then force the output of all composite elements in block style using:

```
yaml.default_flow_style = False
```

If you want finer grained control, create a `ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq` instance:

```
tmp = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq(['http://bio.tools/abyss'])
tmp.fa.set_block_style()
yaml_file_content['extra']['identifiers']['biotools'] = tmp
```

Comment: Thanks, @Anthon. It works perfectly well. It would be great if some of this examples go directly to the documentation to improve the usability of the library.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please consider *accepting* it by clicking the ✔ (checkmark) next to the answer. That is the way other people know your problem has been solved, without reading the comments. It also changes the appearance of the question and this answer in lists. If a better answer comes along, you can always change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have loaded a YAML file it's no longer "yaml"; it's now a Python data structure, and the contents of the `biotools` key is a `list`:

```
>>> import ruamel.yaml as yaml
>>> data = yaml.load(open('data.yml'))
>>> data['extra']['identifiers']['biotools']
['http://bio.tools/abyss']
```

Like any other Python list, you can `append` to it:

```
>>> data['extra']['identifiers']['biotools'].append('http://bio.tools/anothertool')
>>> data['extra']['identifiers']['biotools']
['http://bio.tools/abyss', 'http://bio.tools/anothertool']
```

And if you print out the data structure you get valid YAML:

```
>>> print( yaml.dump(data))
extra:
  identifiers:
    biotools: [http://bio.tools/abyss, http://bio.tools/anothertool]
```

Of course, if for some reason you don't like that list representation you can also get the syntactically equivalent:

```
>>> print( yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=False))
extra:
  identifiers:
    biotools:
    - http://bio.tools/abyss
    - http://bio.tools/anothertool
```

Comment: I have edited my question, The problem is with output, that is using [] in my tool name when I would like to have a new line with `- http://bio.tools/abyss` @larsks

Comment: I'm not sure you've fully understood my answer, but I've added some further examples to try to clarify things.

Comment: `dump() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default_flow_style'` I'm using the `from ruamel.yaml import YAML` with the plugin for jinja2

Comment: What is the value of `ruamel.yaml.__version__`? Can you show, in your question, the *actual code* you are using to load the YAML document?